# Hiding panels with different names in one repeater using jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

can any one help me with hiding panels with different names in repeater using jQuery?

the main logic is that i have documents sorted by year in tabs, and tab name is also year. 
when client clicks on one specific tab, i should provide him to see only documents that have that year as property. documents per year are nested in panel(div),and panel's name is related to tab name, which is year.
i should somehow hit the panel name, and if it's the same name like my tab,to show all documents per year...

thanks in advance!

Comment: Stick everything within an UpdatePanel and use async calls to update the repeater. Why overwork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a CSS class to each element that you want to hide in your repeater, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hideMe').hide();
});
```

To show your elements again, you can call:

```
$('.hideMe').show();
```

Here's a reference to jQuery's [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) functions.